# How do I run a Java program?

Tags: java, user-interface, jar

I've tried to make it work, am I missing a code to make it be able to show the gui on windows,
or do I need some kind of Java to run it?

Here is my code:

```
package math;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame window = new JFrame();
                    window.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: by export do you mean packaging into a jar? if so, and double clicking the jar doesn't open the window, try "java -jar MyJar.jar" in the command line, to get the error messages that may occur

Comment: You're telling US to be specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code compiles and runs fine. (Although it is more appropriate to put setVisible command in the initialize method).

Seems like you could not export it properly. I exported your code with NetBenas and I could run it by double clicking on it. Try exporting your class with NetBenas (It makes it easier).

If you dont have NetBeans and creating the jar file via command line check your manifest file. Make sure you gave the correct main method name.

Answer (score 0):

the Main window part doesn't make sense

replace your try-block

```
 try {
            Main window = new Main();
            window.frame.setVisible(true);
        }
```

with

```
 try {
            initialize();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Comment: window.frame.setVisible(true); He did set it visible, just not where you normally do this :D

Comment: i realized it later :P

Answer (score 0):

you have to set your frame visible in contructor.

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above works fine. It could be that it worked for you but you didn't realize because     the window created is very small. It could also be that you tried to export this into a `.jar` file but didn't specify in the Manifest what the `Main-Class` should be. Depending on the IDE or build tool that you're using, the way might be different. It could also be that you simply do not yet know how to get this code running at all, i.e. compiling and running Java code. In that case, you need to learn about `javac` and `java`, which are included in the Java SDK.

If you use Java 8, you could actually simplify the code. You don't need an exception handler that prints the stack trace, the `EventQueue` is already doing that for you.

```
package math;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            window.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

or, if the code is in a separate method:

```
package math;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(Main::initUI);
    }

    private static void initUI() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If `initUI()` is to be an instance method, you could do it like this:

```
package math;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(this::initUI);
    }

    private void initUI() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```